# Best way to handle files used by python module

Tags: python, file, dependencies

I have a module in site-packages that uses collection of binary files. Besides hard-coding the absolute paths of these files in the module, is there a better way to handle this module-datafile dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Put the data file in a place relative to the module. Use inspect module to figure out the path of the module and then read the data file using this information.